# His vs His (possessive adjective vs possessive pronoun)?

Tags: adjectives, pronouns, possessives, possessive-pronouns

How not to confuse the use of "His (possessive adjective) vs His (possessive pronoun)"?
Is there a rule to use these "pronouns"?

Are possessive pronouns used only after verbs and prepositions?

For example:

The black car next the bakery is his.

Comment: An adjective modifies a noun, a pronoun does not. So it seems impossible to confuse the two uses.

Comment: *his* is never an adjective, it's a Pronoun, a sub-class of Noun. In your sentence - *The black car is his* - the structure is like this - *The black car is [Noun Phrase]*. This Noun Phrase is realized by the single head word - *his*. This pronoun is a possessive pronoun, it shows *possession*; that mean *he owns the black car*.

Comment: @Man There are different ways to categorize words. Whether we call it a possessive adjective or a possessive determiner, this *his* is different to the possessive pronoun *his*, according to many analyses, including those most likely to be familiar to learners.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*His* is confusing, since both the pronoun and the adjective are the same word.  Try substituting in *hers*, *theirs*, *ours*, *yours*, or *mine* if you aren't sure:

> The black car next the bakery is his.

"The black car next to the bakery is *her*?"  No.  "The black car next to the bakery is *hers*."  It's the possessive pronoun.

In general, the possessive adjective is used when directly modifying a noun, and the possessive pronoun is used when it is either the subject or the direct object of the sentence.

More examples:

> *Adjective*: His life is full of adventure.  (*Her* life is full of adventure.)
>
> *Pronoun*: His is a life full of adventure.  (*Theirs* is a life full of adventure.)
>
> *Pronoun*: That thing?  It's his.   (That thing?  It's *mine*.)

And so on.

Answer (score 1):

"His" ("Her") etc. are possessive pronouns: they are in the genitive case of "He" ("She") etc.  The meaning is,"Of him" ("Of her).  Thus even if "His" (etc.) modifies a noun - as in "His book", the meaning remains: "the book of him/belonging to him/possessed by him".

Whatever the post-modernist aliens claim, then, a pronoun in the genitive case remains a pronoun. We might concede, however, that *use* of "his/her" before a noun is adjectival by virtue of syntax.  That is, the **pronoun** is used adjectivally.